# Apache Ignite Application

Tags: ignite

I am building a Java based online application using Java and Ignite. Ignite is used an in memory store/cache and also for data persistence for the application. My question is if I should deploy Ignite in a separate server or should it reside int the same server as the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it both ways, it's up to you.

Comment: I was wondering if there are pros and cons with each of the approach. For e.g. if ignite is on a server by itself then there will be network communication between the app server and ignite server, will that slow down the response times significantly?

Comment: It may decrease latency but throughput should not suffer if used properly, and I think it's usually what counts.